# Bootstrap Carousel not sliding on iphone/ <480px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

My site, like many others, utilizes bootstrap's carousel on the home page.

For some reason, despite the carousel-control appearing and everything else looking fine, the data slide functionality stops working on monitor sizes less than 480px (so, any mobile device).

Is there a snippet of code I need to add to the `@media(max-width:480px)` section in the CSS? As it stands I don't have any carousel/responsive related code under that size, but just the following:

```
@media (max-width: 979px) {
    .carousel .item {
        height: 500px;
    }
    .carousel img {
        width: auto;
        height: 500px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel {
        margin-left: -20px;
        margin-right: -20px;
    }
    .carousel .container {}
    .carousel .item {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .carousel img {
        height: 300px;
    }
    .carousel-caption {
        width: 65%;
        padding: 0 70px;
        margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .carousel-caption h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
    .carousel-caption .lead, .carousel-caption .btn {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
}
```

An example can be seen [here](http://idies.jhu.edu/).

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 2.3.1? Or 3.0.0?

Comment: why not Bootstrap 3.0.0?

Comment: used a base theme on the orchard cms that came with 2.3.1; been meaning to upgrade to 3.0.0 just haven't gotten around to it

Comment: If you want to keep using Bootstrap 2, there is Bootstrap 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a z-index on you carousel-control:

```
    .carousel-control {
    height: 80px;
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: 120px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 99999; /*Add This */
    }
```

What this is doing it just making this control be in front of the slider that is more than the actual screen size.

Comment: thanks @riskbreaker Added z-index, still not working. Though there is the ability to slide when the cursor is placed slightly below the control.

I suppose this is an issue with 2.3.1? [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7367)

Comment: did you already file an issue on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues or search for the bug there?

Comment: @DanielRuf not yet, but ignore my prior comment to riskbreaker--it eventually started working. 

Thank you all so much!

Comment: don't forget to accept his answer if this solved your problem (I have checked it in Google Chrome Dev Tools and the zindex might have fixed it)

Comment: will do! Had a feeling it was going to be the z-index and turns out it was. Worked on the test version of the site; just need to push to production

Comment: Excellent glad to hear :)